# Linkresource URI format not supported error

Tags: c#, uri

Here I encounter the error:

```
LinkedResource imgs = null; 
imgs= new LinkedResource("http://www.com/.../email/new_user_images/footer-bg.jpg");
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? what is the exception?

Comment: @israelaltar The error is : Linkresource URI format not supported error
what im try to do is, i want to send an embedded image on my email, using SSIS script task. some forum use LinkedResource to embed the image. but most of them using local machine as their path. i want to get the image on URL but its not working.

Comment: I know this might be dumb but:

Have you tried using another kind of uri? 

From
    "http://www.com/.../email/new_user_images/footer-bg.jpg"

To something like:
    "http://www.domain.com/Directory/email/new_user_images/footer-bg.jpg"

Comment: @darkndream: Yes, I tried to use this link but still not working : "http://pic-zoom.com/media/images/e4454c8df9.png".